# Assigning to record type arrays in generate statements

Tags: arrays, vhdl, record

How do you use record arrays in generate statements in VHDL? Below is what I have done, which passes synthesis and implementation in Vivado (2021.1). However, when I simulate it, it shows none of the record signals getting assigned and are always "U". I can also not find *any* examples of record fields used in port maps in generate statements.

```
type record_a_t is record
    a : std_logic;
    b : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    c : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    d : std_logic;
    e : std_logic;
end record record_a_t;
type record_a_array_t is array (0 to 3) of record_a_t;

signal record_a_array  : record_a_array_t;
```

Then, I generate the modules with signal mapping like:

```
GEN_MODULES : for i in 0 to 3 generate
    modules : entity work.module
    port map(    
        clk     => clk,
        rst_n   => rst_n,
        a       => record_a_array(i).a,
        b       => record_a_array(i).b,
        c       => record_a_array(i).c,
        d       => record_a_array(i).d,
        e       => record_a_array(i).e
    );
end generate GEN_MODULES;
```

Again, the above seems to pass all the tools syntax checking and builds in Vivado, but simulation (RivPro 2018) and implementation show signals not getting assigned or changing. They are always "U", even if driven from the module. For example, if port `a` is an output that is initialized in the module, `record_a_array(i).c` is always "U". Even the module output port is "U", as if the internal initialization is ignored, which makes no sense to me.

Below is an example.

**Test Module:**

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity module is
    port(    
        clk     : in std_logic;
        rst_n   : in std_logic;
        a       : in std_logic;
        b       : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        c       : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        d       : out std_logic;
        e       : out std_logic
    );
end module;
    
architecture rtl of module is
begin

process(clk, rst_n)
begin
    if(rst_n = '0') then
        b <= (others=> '0');
        c <= (others=> '0');
        d <= '0';
        e <= '0';
    elsif(rising_edge(clk)) then        
        if(a = '1') then
            b <= b + '1';
            c <= c + '1';
            d <= not d;
            e <= not e;
        end if;        
    end if;
end process;

end rtl;
```

**Test Bench:**

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity testbench is
end entity testbench;    
---------------------------------------------------    
architecture arch of testbench is    
---------------------------------------------------  

type record_a_t is record
a : std_logic;
b : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
c : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
d : std_logic;
e : std_logic;
end record record_a_t;

type record_a_array_t is array (0 to 3) of record_a_t;

signal record_a_array  : record_a_array_t;
signal clk : std_logic := '1';
signal rst_n : std_logic := '0';    
---------------------------------------------------
begin

clk  <= not clk  after 5 ns;
rst_n  <= '1' after 20 ns;

GEN_MODULES : for i in 0 to 3 generate
    modules : entity work.module
    port map(    
        clk     => clk,
        rst_n   => rst_n,
        a       => record_a_array(i).a,
        b       => record_a_array(i).b,
        c       => record_a_array(i).c,
        d       => record_a_array(i).d,
        e       => record_a_array(i).e
    );
end generate GEN_MODULES;

process(clk, rst_n)
begin    
    if(rst_n = '0') then
        for i in 0 to 3 loop
            record_a_array(i).a <= '0';
        end loop;
    elsif(rising_edge(clk)) then
        for i in 0 to 3 loop
            record_a_array(i).a <= not record_a_array(i).a;
        end loop;
    end if;    
end process;

end arch;
```

**Simulation:**

[Simulation of module example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wB7e1.png)

Notice how the record signals wired to the module outputs in at the TestBench level are never defined and how the outputs of the generated module instances themselves are not driven, even though they all get asserted in the reset condition. The only signal that gets driven is the 'a' signal from the test bench level.

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. See [ask]

Comment: In -2008 use numeric_std_unsigned. 8. Names, 8.1 General "The _longest static prefix_ of a signal name is the name itself, if the name is a static signal name; otherwise, it is the longest prefix of the name that is a static signal name." 14.7.2 Drivers "There is a single driver for a given scalar signal S in a process statement, provided that there is at least one
signal assignment statement in that process statement and that the longest static prefix of the target signal of that signal assignment statement denotes S or denotes a composite signal of which S is a subelement." Testbench error.

Comment: Your testbench has drivers for all the elements of record_a_array. We can see you're using -2008 when you read mode out ports in the architecture of module. The value of i in the testbench process for loops is not a static value, they are variables.

Comment: @user16145658 - Thanks for the reply! That does work! Ill admit I still don't quite understand the details why yet and will have to take a look in the LRM to the sections you pointed to, but this leads to another question. The above example was simplified with hard coded ranges, but what happens if the upper range of the generate is defined by a generic to scale the number of instantiations? It wouldn't make sense to have to hardcode each index in the architecture as you have shown when the number of indices is unknown. What would be the proper way of handling that situation?

Comment: Generic constants are globally static (IEEE Std 1076-2008 9.4 Static expressions). You don't have dynamically sized hardware. The distinction between a for generate scheme and a for loop is in the use of globally static values versus variables (for loops are only unrolled in synthesis, which as you say worked).

Answer (score 0):

Since the record is not crossing into the RTL space, unwanted drivers can be turned off using std_logic using 'Z':

```
  constant REC_INIT : record_a_t := (
     a => 'Z',
     b => "ZZZZZZZZ",
     c => "ZZZZ",
     d => 'Z',
     e => 'Z'
   ) ;
   . . . 
   signal record_a_array  : record_a_array_t := (0 to 3 => REC_INIT) ;
```

As you start to look at the issue in the LRM, you might also note you can find the issues the IEEE VHDL working group has recorded at:  :  https://gitlab.com/IEEE-P1076/VHDL-Issues/-/issues.   There is a remotely related issue in https://gitlab.com/IEEE-P1076/VHDL-Issues/-/issues/275 that may be able to address both its issue and this one - though time will tell on that.

For verification, I use Open Source VHDL Verification Methodology (OSVVM).   We use records on ports and as a result, use special resolution functions with them so they do not require initialization.